# Sql link other tables as one column

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have the following table Table1:

```
id │ value_one │  
───┼───────────┼
1  │ a         │         
2  │ b         │
```

Table2:

```
id │ value_two │ table1_id │ value_three
───┼───────────┼───────────┼───────
1  │ a1        │ 1         │ a2
2  │ b1        │ 1         │ b2
```

I want to get result as below which bind tables2 which table1_id = 1 into list as column

```
{
 "value_one":"a",
 "from_table2":[
 {"value_two":"a1","value_three":"a2"},  
 {"value_two":"b1","value_three":"b2"}
 ]            
}
```

Which SQL (sql server) query should I use?

---

@@ Sorry, I use ...azure SQL Database .....

(Azure SQL Database V12 have their compatibility level start at 130, which matches Microsoft SQL Server 2016 GA.)

and want use query string in nodejs.

```
var queryString = "";
var query = {
  sql: queryString
};
req.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
```

Comment: No SQL query is going to return JSON, unless you are asking about SQL Server 2016 specifically. You need to write *code* that takes query results and serializes them to JSON

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I almost read that as a recommendation for "NoSQL". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Comment: Seems like FOR JSON PATH... What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Alec NoSQL databases aren't going to return JSON automagically either

Comment: What SQL Server version are we talking about?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos is right. It's SQL Server 2016 which use in azure.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I know, that was my point.

Comment: Added two versions, check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have possibility to test solution in SQL Server 2016, but one can do it in earlier versions of SQL Server as follows:

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b')) T(id, value_one)
), Table2 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'a1', 1, 'a2'),
    (2, 'b1', 1, 'b2')
    ) T(id, value_two, table1_id, value_three)
), RowValues AS
(
    SELECT '{"value_one":'+QUOTENAME(value_one, '"')+',"from_table2":['+
        STUFF((SELECT ',{"value_two":'+QUOTENAME(value_two, '"')+',"value_three":'+QUOTENAME(value_three, '"')+'}'
        FROM Table2
        WHERE T1.id=table1_id
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
        +']}' RowValue
    FROM Table1 T1
)
SELECT *
FROM RowValues
WHERE RowValue IS NOT NULL
```

It produces:

```
{"value_one":"a","from_table2":[{"value_two":"a1","value_three":"a2"},{"value_two":"b1","value_three":"b2"}]}
```

---

SQL Server 2016, FOR JSON

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b')
    ) T(id, value_one )
), Table2 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'a1', 1, 'a2'),
    (2, 'b1', 1, 'b2')
    ) T(id, value_two, table1_id, value_three)
)
SELECT R FROM Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT T1.value_one,
        (SELECT value_two, value_three FROM Table2 WHERE table1_id=T1.id FOR JSON PATH) fromTable2
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) T(R)
--WHERE id=1--optional filter
```

It would be easier to include whole result as one JSON, but it seems against your assumptions.